# The kivy python language is it possible to change the background colors in the spinner menu?

Tags: python, kivy, spinner

I’d like to do, something similar a combobox in tkinter. I think this is a spinner in kivy.
I can do a spinner, but i can’t change the background color in menu itens.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'kv' use:

```
<SpinnerOption>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 1,0,0,1
```

`SpinnerOption` is the class used for the `Spinner` dropdown `Buttons`.